ElasticSearch Aggregations with Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch
I am having the hardest time converting this elastic search query into .NET client version 8 format. Could you please help me?
Query:
GET stediresponses/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "parentId": {
              "value": "16fda1d8-2e9f-402e-ac76-0d01615b371f"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "responseType": {
              "value": "835"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "practitioner_sum": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "practitionerId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_payment": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "totalActualProviderPaymentAmount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I've tried the following code but it will not compile. Examples online and Generative Ai all say this should work but .Terms isn't valid according to Visual Studio.
Using these package namespaces.
using Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch;
using Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.Aggregations;
using Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.QueryDsl;

var searchResponse = await _elasticSearchClient.SearchAsync<StediClaimResponse>( s => s 
    .Aggregations( a => a
        .Terms( "practitioner_sum", t => t
            .Field( "practitionerId" )
            .Aggregations( aa => aa
                .Sum( "total_payment", sa => sa
                    .Field( "totalActualProviderPaymentAmount" )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

StediClaimResponse index document looks like this. (Removed most of the information for posting here)
{
          "source": "Blue Cross and Blue Shield of Texas",
          "claimId": "",
          "fhirClaimId": "",
          "responseType": "835",
          "transactionId": "",
          "status": "Payment",
          "statusCode": "1",
          "statusCategory": "",
          "statusCategoryCode": "",
          "controlNumber": "",
          "tradingPartnerServiceId": "",
          "tradingPartnerClaimNumber": "",
          "messages": [],
          "aiSummary": "",
          "isRejected": false,
          "information837": {},
          "totalActualProviderPaymentAmount": 448,
          "practitionerId": "-",
          "practitionerFhirId": "-",
          "practitionerName": "-",
          "practitionerPhoto": "",
          "practitionerPhotoTransparent": "",
          "id": "01J4DB4P7D2BJ69FAQX75SPEHT",
          "parentId": "",
          "dateCreated": "2024-08-04T00:03:01.4882155Z",
          "dateModified": "2024-08-04T00:03:01.4882787Z",
          "elementTypeId": 19,
          "isDeleting": false,
          "dateCreatedDate": "8/4/2024",
          "dateModifiedDate": "8/4/2024"
        }

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Show us the definition of StediClaimResponse.

I have updated my question to include the index document structure.

The following blog link (https://www.elastic.co/search-labs/blog/net-client-evolution) from Elastic Search pointed me in the right direction. 777
    .Aggregations( aggs => aggs
        .Add( "practitioner_sum", agg => agg
            .Terms( tt => tt
                .Field( "practitionerId" )
            )
            .Aggregations( childAggs => childAggs
                .Add( "total_payment", agg => agg.Sum( sumAggregation )
                )
            )
        )
    )

The ".Add( "practitioner_sum", agg => agg" part is what examples online and generative A.I. was missing.

Thank you for this! A lot of Elastic docs are out of date. Including NEST examples when we need Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.x type examples now. This helped me get my data to match the Kibana dashboard quickly.
